# Получение данных в переменную python, telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Делаю бота, использую **поэтапный оброботчик**, мне нужно получить **ин-фо из вопроса бота в переменную date (и создать её)** для дальнейшего добовления в бд, как это сделать? **Заранее спасибо!**

P.S: *обротите внимание на коментарии к коду*

P.S.s: *как добовлять что-то в бд я знаю, вопрос заключается в том как мне достать ин-фо от пользователя в отделюную переменную*

Код:

```
import telebot

token = "token"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["add"])
def add(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Желаете добавить задачу?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_answer)

def user_answer(message):
    if message.text == "да":
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите дату для задачи:")#из этого вопроса
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_date)
    elif message.text == "нет":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ОК!")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ntry)
            
def user_date(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Your date:")#тут должна выводится дата пользователю + сохронятся (для дальнейшено добовления в бд)

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)

bot.load_next_step_handlers()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то вот вам сыль: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Нет, не то. Нужно именно "достать" сообщение пользователя в отдельную переменную

Comment: @ДмитрийКапралов в таком случае создайте глобальную переменную со значением None и в функции user_data сохраните в нее message

Comment: подскажите код, сложно